# Reverse the order of pause when used with a stack

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, navigation, pause, stack

I'm drawing a stack in beamer using `drawstack` package. I want to show the evolution of the stack by using `pause`. In `tikzpicture`, `pause` moves forward, but a stack is drawn in the reverse order. How do I get the pauses right to show the evolution of the stack. I can think of workarounds using multiple frames each showing the evolution, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nocolor]{drawstack}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\stacktop{} \cellptr{top of stack}
\separator
\cell{c} \cellcomL{2};
\separator
\cell{b} \cellcomL{1};
\separator
\cell{a} \cellcomL{0};
\separator
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `\pause` I'd recommend using a key `visible on` as defined in the preamble of the following MWE. The trick is to enclose each level of stack in a `scope` environment, and pass the key `visible on=<num>` to the environment to set the overlay effects. I also had to redefine the `\cellptr` command in the `drawstack` package to prevent the top right arrow to wiggle between frames.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}

\usepackage[nocolor]{drawstack}
\renewcommand{\cellptr}[1]{
  \draw[<-,line width=0.7pt] (0,0) +(2,0) -- +(2.5,0) node[anchor=west] {#1};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[visible on=<4->]
  \stacktop{} \cellptr{top of stack}
  \separator
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[visible on=<3->]
  \cell{c} \cellcomL{2};
  \separator
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[visible on=<2->]
  \cell{b} \cellcomL{1};
  \separator
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[visible on=<1->]
  \cell{a} \cellcomL{0};
  \separator
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For the top of stack indicator, can we have it on each frame as shown in the question?

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Yes. Just replace `visible on=<4->` with `visible on=<1->` in the `scope` associated with drawing the top stack.

Comment: thanks. But this will create a hole between `a` and `top of stack`  in frame1

Comment: @arunmoezhi (sry2necro & jfcs) A simple way is to use "visible on=<n>" instead of "visible on=<n->" to show a shifted version each time. For that give the "cellptr" an optional argument, with which you replace the "(0,0)" inside. Then the opt-args are [], [(0,-1)], [(0,-2)], and [(0,-3)]  (basically "[(0, <n-4>)]")

Answer (score 8):

A solution with a simple tabular:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
\usetheme{Malmoe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stack with a tabular}\arrayrulewidth=1pt
 \begin{tabular}{@{} l | 
    >{\columncolor{black!10}\centering\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}p{3cm} |@{} r}\cline{2-2}
    & \ldots & $\longleftarrow$ top of stack \\\cline{2-2} \onslide<3->
  2 &   c    &                   \\\cline{2-2} \onslide<2->
  1 &   b    &                   \\\cline{2-2} \onslide<1->
  0 &   a    &                   \\\cline{2-2}  
 \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution with a simple `makebox` and without holes:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\newcommand\MBox[2]{\makebox[1em]{#1}~\fbox{\makebox[3cm]{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stack with Boxes}\offinterlineskip
\onslide+<1->{\MBox{}{\ldots}$\longleftarrow$ top of stack\\}
\only<3->   {\MBox2c\\}
\only<2->   {\MBox1b\\}
\only<1->   {\MBox0a}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Can the `top of stack` be dynamically moved. For instance, in frame1, `top of stack` has to be just above `a` with no holes in between

Comment: see my edited answer, the second variant.

Comment: I get a compilation error at line 14 "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end." I'm using LuaLatex to compile

Comment: I used xelatex and had no problem.will have a look tomorrow

Comment: Using xelatex/LuaLatex gives the same compilation error. But surprisingly the output pdf file is generated. The output file looks just fine. Thanks

Comment: See my edited answer. Put the \\  before the `}` or use `\par` instead of \\

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Can you please add some explanation to this solution.